# Random <C-L> inserted into Majaro

Tags: virtualbox, macintosh, manjaro

I am running Manjaro in Virtualbox under Mac OSX host. when I type `should` it randomly inserts `<C-L>` at the character `l`. This happens more frequently if I type quickly, but never occurs if I key in character by character.

This is how it looks like in Vim. At other places, it has the same effect of `Ctrl + L` (clear text in a terminal, Chrome textbox etc)

I tried clearing all hotkeys in Virtualbox and uncheck `Auto Capture Keyboard`, disabling error correct in Mac OSX but it does not help. What is causing this weird behavior?

[image: random <C-L> inserted]